# Unable to install the correct software version via apt

Tags: 18.04, apt, ppa

I installed KiCad using the Ubuntu Software application.
It installed version 4.0.7 which seems to be outdated.

When I started it I encountered cursor ghosting like in the screenshot below.

This is usually fixed by installing the latest build, following https://kicad-pcb.org/download/ubuntu/

But no matter how hard I try I did not manage to install version 5.16. It always installs 4.0.7.

```
$ sudo apt list kicad
Listing... Done
kicad/bionic,now 4.0.7+dfsg1-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-5.1-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

the source is being updated so why can't I get the software from it?

How can I get a newer software version from a source other than the official Ubuntu repository?

[image]

Comment: thanks @user535733. this tells me why Ubuntu repositories do not provide latest versions. but why do I get the old version with the devs ppa as source? how to I get the newer version from a source other than the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: PPA is a personal archive. Only its owner knows why they don't update it.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's the devs' official source for the software, I followed their install instructiosn for that version and as many suggest this as the solution to the rendering problem I suppose it yields the correct version for others.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1261512/edit) to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy kicad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visit the ppa url, given below, you will find that it has packages of kicad-5.1 for Ubuntu-19.10 and Ubuntu-20.04 only.

http://ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-5.1-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kicad/

Comment: It is available for Ubuntu-18.04 in one of on Kicad's contributor's (Jean-Samuel Reynaud) PPA.
https://launchpad.net/~js-reynaud/+archive/ubuntu/kicad-5

Comment: thanks, that's how I actually solved it. I derived the PPA from the instructions for an older version mentioned in the docs.